# Regenerating system in my game not working as intended

Tags: java

I am programming a simple 3D java game in my free time, and I am implementing a health system, you get 5 hearts, and when, for instance, you swim in lava you lose one heart every 0.4 seconds, but when you get out of the lava it should regenerate one heart every 2 seconds, this is not working as intended. The losing of my health works, but as soon I step out of the lava I stay at the amount of hearts i have left and won't regenerate any.

Here is the relevant piece of code for my problem:

```
public void updateHealthBar(Player player, Screen screen) {
    if(player.isSwimmingInLava) {
        player.isGettingDamage = true;
        if(System.currentTimeMillis() >= lastTime) {
            lastTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + 400;
            this.playerHealth--;
        } else {
            player.isGettingDamage = false;
        }
    }
    if(!(player.isSwimmingInLava) && !(this.playerHealth < 5) && System.currentTimeMillis() >= lastTime) {
        lastTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + 2000;
        this.playerHealth++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the part `!(this.playerHealth < 5)` of your last if condition should not be negated.

Comment: Darn, I overlooked that! Thanks mate.